# How to update my column Value=Value+1 ?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to update `test1` table some rows. `ColumnB` must be 10 11,12,13,14 ....
But My table

For example:

ColumnA is parent node. ColumnA+ColumnB is primary Key. Forexample ColumnA is CustomerNumber. ColumnB is Customer' ordernumber.

```
create table test1(ColumnA int,  ColumnB int,  ColumnC int);
Insert Into test1 Values(1, 9,123);
Insert Into test1 Values(1, 10,0);
Insert Into test1 Values(1, 10,0);
Insert Into test1 Values(1, 10,0);
Insert Into test1 Values(1, 10,0);
Insert Into test1 Values(2, 12,128);
Insert Into test1 Values(2, 12,0);
Insert Into test1 Values(3, 11,145);
Insert Into test1 Values(3, 11,0);
```

it should not that:

[image]

it should be that below:

[image]

My not working code:

```
    update a set a.ColumnB=a.ColumnB+1
from test1 a 
inner join test1 b
on b.ColumnA=a.ColumnA
and a.ColumnC=0;
select * from test1;
```

How can I do that? How to update my first table to second one.

Comment: The order of rows in your table is undefined.  Is there a primary key or identity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ColumnA
                      ORDER BY ColumnB) AS RN
  FROM test1
)
UPDATE t 
SET t.ColumnB = CASE 
                  WHEN RN = 1 THEN ColumnB 
                  ELSE ColumnB + RN - 1 
                END  
FROM CTE AS t;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9e92a/1)

Answer (score 3):

Please try:

```
with T as(
select 
    row_number() over (partition by ColumnA order by ColumnA) Rnum, 
    min(ColumnB) over (partition by ColumnA) MinVal, 
    * 
From test1
) update T set ColumnB=MinVal+(Rnum-1)
```

Comment: This is beyond my SQL skill level but at least it's obvious that this is the only answer so far that actually addresses the problem.

Comment: If this does not increase ColumnB for the rows where `ColumnC <> 0`, that's by accident.